# "the shadow of a doubt" or "a shadow of a doubt" or "shadow of doubt"

Tags: phrase-usage, articles, definite-article, indefinite-article, idiomatic-language

It seems all these three versions are in use: "the shadow of a doubt", "a shadow of a doubt", and "shadow of doubt", as suggested by Google Dictionary and Google search results. Google Dictionary (partially from the ODO):

> shadow
>   noun.
>   the slightest trace of something.
>   *"she knew without a shadow of a doubt that he was lying"
>
>   "she knew without any shadow of doubt"*

I have always thought "doubt" should follow an article, but strangely the article-less version seems more popular according to Ngram. Any difference in meaning? Or is this a BrE/AmE difference?

Google Ngram:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm British and had never thought about this. They all seem equally correct to me as would:

*without any shadow of doubt*

*without the slightest shadow of a doubt*

*beyond a shadow of a doubt*

At this point the whole expression ceases to look meaningful to me so I'll stop.